# Native Token Names: How may I prevent other Projects from using my Project's Cardano Native Token Ticker/Name (fungible) on any blockchain network?

Tags: token, name

I am starting a new blockchain project.  I think I want to deploy the project on Cardano.  When I select a fungible Token Name for my Native Token on Cardano,  how do I prevent another project from using the exact same Token Name as I have used?    I have not found a global registry, like that used for IP addresses/names on TCPIP.   What if a project on another blockchain, say, Ethereum tries to use my exact same Token name, are they blocked somehow?

Also, if another project is not blocked from using my exact same Token Name, how can the fungible tokens be traded on an exchange?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Tokens are identified on Cardano by their policy id. This will be completely unique to your token when you mint it. You can then register your token in the github token registry. Wallets like Daedalus will use this information to determine how to display your token in the wallets. The CardanoFoundation maintains this repository so they can clean up any scam tokens that are trying to impersonate yours.

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry